# Extract xlink:href attribute from XML

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xlink

I'm trying to parse an XML but I've got problems when trying to extract a link from the response.

My XML looks like:

```
<properties xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lastUpdate="2016-11-23">
    <property myId="3" lastUpdate="2016-11-20T01:25:17+01:00" xlink:href="http://example.com/webservice/rest/1/properties/3"/>
    <property myId="10" lastUpdate="2016-11-16T03:52:54+01:00" xlink:href="http://example.com/webservice/rest/1/properties/10"/>
    ...
```

And my function:

```
    r = requests.get(url, auth=(self.usr, self.psw))
    xml = r.content
    root = ET.fromstring(xml)
    for prop in root:
        m_id= prop.attrib['myId']
        my_url = prop.attrib['xlink:href']
```

I can extract the `id` attribute, but **I get an error** when tries to get the URL

Comment: "It crashes"? As in, your screen goes black and your computer restarts?

Comment: Seriously though: I am fairly sure the duplicate thread answers your question, because it covers the one thing you code is missing. If that's not the case, please be more specific about what the issue is and I will re-open the question.